# Self hosted owin webapi app cannot find connection string in web.config

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, owin, dbcontext

My webapi application, which runs fine when launched from visual studio throws the following error when running on OWIN self host:

> "No connection string named 'ProductsDbContext' could be found in the
>   application config file."

**Does OWIN need some extra configuration to access the Web.config file?**

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(config);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

and my self host code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ListScorecardSlices()
    {
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAddress))
        { 
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/products(2)").Result;
            var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is in the web.config and where does the test method live? It will need it's own config file.

Comment: The test method is in a different project. Thanks. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hosting your OWIN in some kind of service or another non-web application (which is likely, because why else would you need self-host), then you'd need not the `web.config` file, but application config file, that has the name of `<your executable name with extension>.config`. If you add `app.config` file to your executable project, Visual Studio will automatically place it with the executable.